# Change $(img).offset() when image is moved onclick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, onclick

I have an image which changes position randomly when I click on it. I want to play one of three possible different sounds depending on if the click is:

- on the image
- 50px away from the image
- more than 50px away from the image.

To do so I need to save the image's coordinates so that they are updated every time the image is moved. I have this code:

```js
function move() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  var img = document.getElementById("myImage");

  //FIND CENTER OF IMAGE 
  var offset = $(img).offset();
  var width = $(img).width();
  var height = $(img).height();

  // PLAY DIFFERENT SOUND
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target === img) {
      audio.src = "sound1.mp3";
      audio.play();
    } else if (e.clientX < (offset.left - 50) || e.clientX > (offset.left + width + 50) || e.clientY < (offset.top - 50) || e.clientY > (offset.top + height + 50)) {
      audio.src = "sound2.mp3";
      audio.play();
    } else {
      audio.src = "sound3.mp3";
      audio.play();
    }
    // GENERATE RANDOM LOCATION
    // Fix this part
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

    img.style.top = x + "px";
    img.style.left = y + "px";
    img.style.bottom = x - "px";
    img.style.right = y - "px";
  }, false);
}
```

There must some small mistakes in updating the coordinates of the image. Any ideas why?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Are there any errors? How does your script behave?

Comment: The image changes position when I click on it, sound1 is always correctly played when the click is on the image, but the program doesn't update the location of the image and as a consequence offset, width and height are always the ones corresponding to the first appearance of the image (in the centre). I think that I am misusing the $() syntax.

Comment: You cache your img's height, width and offset. Move the declaration and functions to obtain these parameters into click event handler.

Comment: @Oskar could you advise me on how to do so please?

Comment: @Gigi I don't know the whole context, where your 'move' function is used, but I'll try to prepare an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you have your variable `offset` cached for each click, try moving assignment to the click handler. Also extract the event listener from your move function to avoid memory leaks. In your case, each time you fire the `move` function, a new event listener is attached. Ensure your `<img id="myImage" />` has `position` set for `fixed` or `absolute` to a relative element. In case you use a relative element you have to change `$window` to your relative elements to get the right size.

```js
  var $audio = $('#audio');
  var $img = $("#myImage");
  var $window = $(window);

  var width = $img.width();
  var height = $img.height();
  var maxX = $window.width() - width;
  var maxY = $window.height() - height;
  
  function move() {
    //Get a new position, use modulo operation to get x from range (0, windowWidth - imageWidth) and y from range (0, windowHeight - imageHeight)
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) % maxX;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) % maxY;

    $img.css('left', x + 'px');
    $img.css('top', y + 'px');
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    //get the img offset
    var offset = $img.offset();
    if (e.target === $img[0]) {
      audio.src = "sound1.mp3";
      audio.play();
    } else if (e.clientX < (offset.left - 50) || e.clientX > (offset.left + width + 50) || e.clientY < (offset.top - 50) || e.clientY > (offset.top + height + 50)) {
      audio.src = "sound2.mp3";
      audio.play();
    } else {
      audio.src = "sound3.mp3";
      audio.play();
    }
    
    move();
  }, false);
```

Comment: @Gigi I am glad I could help. You can accept my answer by clicking on the gray tick below the score of my answer. If you like it, you can also vote it up by using the arrow above the score. Thanks!